# I wanna my private blockchain network with stellar

Tags: stellar-core, horizon

I wanna my private blockchain network with stellar

but it's not working

here is my configure

```
# What port stellar-core listens for commands on. This is for Horizon server.

HTTP_PORT=11626

ALLOW_LOCALHOST_FOR_TESTING=true

ARTIFICIALLY_ACCELERATE_TIME_FOR_TESTING=true

PUBLIC_HTTP_PORT=true

KNOWN_CURSORS=["HORIZON"]

# If it is true, It prevents you from trying to connect to other peers

RUN_STANDALONE=false

# A phrase for your network. All nodes should have the same network phrase.

NETWORK_PASSPHRASE="xx Standalone Pramati Network ; Oct 2018"

# The seed used for generating the public key this node will be identified within SCP.

NODE_SEED="XXXX self"

# Only nodes that want to participate in SCP should set NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true.

# Most instances should operate in observer mode with NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=false.

NODE_IS_VALIDATOR=true

# Comma separated peers list

KNOWN_PEERS=["
xxxxx:11625", "
xxxxx:11625", "
xxxxx:11625"]

PREFERRED_PEERS=["
xxxxx:11625", "
xxxxx:11625", "
xxxxx:11625"]

PREFERRED_PEER_KEYS=["xxxxx", "xxxx", "xxxxx"]

# Postgres DB URL

DATABASE="postgresql://dbname=stellar_node01_db host=localhost user=xx password=xxx"

# The port other instances of stellar-core can connect to you on.

PEER_PORT=11625

# Log level setup

COMMANDS=["ll?level=info"]

FAILURE_SAFETY=0

UNSAFE_QUORUM=true

#The public keys of the Stellar servers

[QUORUM_SET]

THRESHOLD_PERCENT=100

# comma sepearted validator list

VALIDATORS=["$self", "xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx"]

[HISTORY.local]

get="cp /mnt/xvdf/stellar-core-archive/node_001/{0} {1}"

put="cp {0} /mnt/xvdf/stellar-core-archive/node_001/{1}"

mkdir="mkdir -p /mnt/xvdf/stellar-core-archive/node_001/{0}"
```

others are almost same. they all connected but when I typed "stellar-core http-command info", state is not change with "state" : "Joining SCP"

and when I trying to start horizon server with follow command

```
horizon --db-url "postgresql://xxx:xxxx@localhost:5432/stellar_horizon_db" --history-archive-urls "
http://xxxx.site" --stellar-core-url "
http://127.0.0.1:11626" --network-passphrase="xxx Standalone Pramati Network ; Oct 2018" --ingest --captive-core-config-path "/etc/default/stellar-captive-core.toml" --stellar-core-binary-path=$(which stellar-core)
```

it said

```
ERRO[2021-06-24T08:24:57.846Z] Error in ingestion state machine current_state="resume(latestSuccessfullyProcessedLedger=1)" error="error preparing range: error starting prepare range: opening subprocess: error calculating ledger and hash for stelar-core run: error trying to read ledger header 3 from HAS: error opening ledger stream: Bad HTTP response '500 Internal Server Error' for GET '
https://xxxx.site/ledger/00/00/00/ledger-0000003f.xdr.gz'" next_state=start pid=25160 service=ingest
```

please help me if you know what I have to do

thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to kickstart your network by restarting one node with the `force-scp` option.

@see [Fork stellar to create a new blockchain](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/2493/fork-stellar-to-create-a-new-blockchain)